# duplicated objects dont show up in render

Tags: mesh, linked-data

ive got a fairly high poly grass object that will not load in my renders. ive looked at camera settings, ensured they are not hidden, etc. 
i have been having issues with duplicated objects not showing up regardless of shift-D or alt-D, they also seem to have a different rotation and placement than the original.

it shows in the viewport, but nowhere else. maybe this is to do with unlinked data blocks, but as far as i know all the necessary data is there... ive tried setting back to default preferences, fiddling with a bunch of things but ive probably done more harm than good. so i really dont know. any tips?

[image]

[image]

here is a screenshot of it in the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can resolve it for you - but I don't really know why?

If you run your animation (before deleting the keyframes) all three objects are instantly moved on top of each other. So it is probably rendering all duplicates, it is just that they are on top of each other. I wonder if it has something to do with Blender effectively starting the frame 1 animation prior to rendering an image? Someone smarter may be able to help here.

Anyhow, for the duplicated objects remove the associated keyframes (in the Animation workspace) and now the duplicates are now rendered.

Here is a rendered output example.
[image]

Comment: you got it. must have accidentally hit spacebar, recorded on some frames while making some transformations meaning my render was showing up at the wrong time basically. setting frame to 0, deleting my keyframes and inserting a new one, copying my objects into the scene fixed this.